# Conditional insert or update in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with input of type time and I want to check first if there is a row with the current date and the id of employee, if it was I update the value of the input if not I insert a new row. This is what I have tried but it always inserts a new row even if the condition exists:

```
<?php 

$E1=$_POST['E1'];

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "ntr-ktb123", "absence"); 
$sql1="SELECT * FROM retards WHERE Date ='Curdate()' AND 
IdEmpl='".$_POST["IdEmp"]."' ;";
$result1=mysqli_query($connect,$sql1);
if(!$result1){
       die('ERREUR SQL ! <br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysqli_error());}
    if($dt=mysqli_fetch_array($result1,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

$sql="update retards set E1='$E1'  where IdEmpl='".$_POST["IdEmp"]."' AND 
 Date=CURDATE();";
}

else{

$sql="insert into retards(IdEmpl,Date,E1) values 
('".$_POST["IdEmp"]."',CURDATE(),'$E1'); ";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
if (!$result)
  {
 echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($connect));
 }
else {
$message ="Effectué avec succès!";

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message'); </script>";
}
mysqli_close($connect);

 ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as an upsert which can be done in mysql using the [`insert ... on duplicate key update`](http://:%20https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax.

```
insert into t (a, b, c) values (?, ?, ?)
on duplicate key update b = ?
```

Your table should have an appropriate unique index or primary key defined on the column(s) of interest.

Comment: You can also do `UPDATE b=VALUES(b)` if you want to set `b` to whatever you were trying to set it to in the first place.